# Cannot use 'for' keyword in HTML tags for R Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to create custom radio buttons in R Shiny using HTML syntax. However, the  tag uses the 'for' keyword and R is interpreting that as the 'for' in 'for loops'.

```
 tags$label(class = 'custom-control-label',
            for = 'customRadio1',
            'Cumulative Graph')
```

Anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you try  ?  `HTML(' Your HTML Codes  ')`.. Like the **Raw HTML** section at [this site](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-tags.html#:~:text=You%20cannot%20put%20raw%20HTML,text%20to%20your%20UI%20document.&text=To%20add%20raw%20HTML%2C%20use,class%20of%20object%20in%20Shiny).

Comment: Yes that works too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose `for` in backticks:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$label(class = 'custom-control-label',
             `for` = 'customRadio1',
             'Cumulative Graph')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```